# Search for info and add from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcqpZ.png)

Image 1 This is the format which people Will full, the example searches for 716

Image 2 Then the 716 format where it should paste the info is like this (It already has info)

Image 3 Adding the info should end up like this (adding the info below the old info instead of rewriting it)

I have a code that searches for a value in another sheet, after searching i want to copy what the original sheet has bellow in another cells, but i want to oly copy what has information. Then return to the value found and paste bellow last cell with information.

Since the sheet bancos has more info the code is replacing the information that is in there, instead i would like it to search for last unused cell 4 rows bellow 1 on the left and start searching 10 rows also below and paste the info on BU worksheet.

This is for a new format where its always going to search for cell "C3" And add information from "B7:C19"

```
Private Sub C1_Click()

Dim Partida As String
Dim Rng As Range, r1 As Range, r As Long, c As Long

Partida = Worksheets("BU").Range("C3").Value

    If Trim(Partida) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Bancos").Rows("6:6")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=Partida, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                r = Rng.Row + 4
                c = Rng.Column - 1
                For Each r1 In Worksheets("Bu").Range("b7:c19")
                    If Len(r1) > 0 Then
                        .Cells(r, c + r1.Column - 2).Value = r1.Value
                        r = r + 1
                    End If
                Next r1
                Else
                MsgBox "No se encontró, desea agregar la partida: " & Worksheets("BU").Range("C3").Value
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

No error msgs tho

Comment: I recognise that code! I can see I missed something which would account for the pair being broken up. Not sure about the other problem. Do you ever have a value in eg B7 but nothing in C7 or vice versa or is it only ever both cells blank?

Comment: Hey! Yeah i didn't want to bother you again with another issue, and no if b7 has info, c7 has to have. It has either both cells filled, or both in blank. Ty so much for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've changed a couple of lines, as indicated below, which I hope will resolve your problems.

```
Private Sub C1_Click()

Dim Partida As String
Dim Rng As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

Partida = Worksheets("BU").Range("C3").Value

    If Trim(Partida) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Bancos").Rows("6:6")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=Partida, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1).End(xlDown)
                If r2.Row > 19 Then
                    Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1)
                Else
                    Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                End If
                For Each r1 In Worksheets("Bu").Range("B7:B19")
                    If Len(r1) > 0 Then
                        r2.Resize(, 2).Value = r1.Resize(, 2).Value
                        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                    End If
                Next r1
            Else
                MsgBox "No se encontró, desea agregar la partida: " & Worksheets("BU").Range("C3").Value
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah! The pair is now complete thank you! Now im trying to figure out why it always goes for the same row, but thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it always goes for the same row"? Do you mean the answers are overwritten or it starts in the wrong row? It should be 4 rows down and 1 column to the left of where `partida` is found.

Comment: I think i explained it bad, what i wanted was once it has the info on BU sheet, i want it to go to Bancos sheet and detect last info on, lets say 1 column on the left, 4 rows bellow, and starting from there and ending 10 rows below again. Im sorry if i didnt explain it well :( You dont have to answer me u have alredy helped me a lot!! I dont want to bother :p

Comment: Don't worry, I'm happy to help. I've just seen one thing I overlooked which is that because of this line `With Sheets("Bancos").Rows("6:6")` the destination cells I used will be out by 6 rows. So if `Rng` is H6 you want to go to G10, and then go down from there to find the first unused cell or start pasting in G10?

Comment: Ohhh so it does detect that on the row 6+4 has no info so thats why it pase it there?? Im trying to understand lul

Comment: Yes except that I think it was pasting in 6+4+6 because of the `Rows("6:6")` I overlooked.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly the point! And i want to start on G10 and find the last unused cell.

Comment: Sorry missed something else. Try it now.

Comment: Assuming partida is only there once, let's remove the After parameter - try it now.

Comment: Im so sorry!! Now it replace it, it doesnt look for the last unused cell.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot which shows what you want to happen, will probably save some time?

Comment: OK slightly different approach. Not sure how it will work in practice with that limited range, assuming the Total is fixed at row 20.

Comment: Oh yeah dont worry about the total :)

Comment: I've put in a check to see how far down the data goes, which may not be necessary, in which case can remove `If r2.Row > 19 Then`.